# Extracting field values and file content from multipart/form-data posted to AWS Lambda (Python)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, multipartform-data, werkzeug

I have created an API in AWS API Gateway and connected it to an AWS Lambda backed that is written in Python. The HTML form has 7 fields, i.e., hotelName and hotelCity, and an image file.

I am not very well versed in Python, but I am trying to use the formparser.py class in **'werkzeug'** library to parse the multipart/form-data. I

I have also uploaded all the dependencies including the werkzeug module to AWS as a Layer.

The part of the code that I use to extract the field names and file content is this. I get all sorts of errors when trying to get this work:

```
form_data = parse_form_data({}, stream_factory=lambda: BytesIO(body))
form_values = form_data[0]
form_files = form_data[1]
```

I have spent hours trying to get this working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Full code:

```
import json
import boto3
import logging
from werkzeug.formparser import parse_form_data
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request
import base64
import jwt
import os
import uuid

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def handler(event, context):

    headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
    }

    body = event["body"]
    isBase64Encoded = bool(event["isBase64Encoded"])
    
    if isBase64Encoded:
        body = base64.b64decode(body)
    else:
        body = body.encode('utf-8')

    # Parse multipart/form data (includs an uploaded image)
    form_data = parse_form_data({}, stream_factory=lambda: BytesIO(body))
    
    form_values = form_data[0]
    form_files = form_data[1]

    # End of Parse multipart/form 

    hotel_name = form.get('hotelName')
    hotel_rating = form.get('hotelRating')
    hotel_city = form.get('hotelCity')
    hotel_price = form.get('hotelPrice')
    file_name = form.get('fileName')
    user_id = form.get('userId')
    id_token = form.get('idToken')
    
    logger.info(hotel_name)
    
    file = files.get('fileData').read().decode()

    token = jwt.decode(id_token, verify=False)
    group = token.get("cognito:groups")

    if group is None or group != "Admin":
        return {
            "statusCode": 401,
            "body": json.dumps({
                "Error": "You are not a member of the Admin group"
            })
        }

    bucket_name = os.environ.get("bucketName")
    region = os.environ.get("AWS_REGION")

    s3_client = boto3.client("s3", region_name=region)
    dynamoDb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name=region)
    table = dynamoDb.Table("Hotels")

    try:
        s3_client.put_object(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=file_name,
            Body=file
        )

        hotel = {
            "UserId": user_id,
            "Id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "Name": hotel_name,
            "CityName": hotel_city,
            "Price": int(hotel_price),
            "Rating": int(hotel_rating),
            "FileName": file_name
        }

        table.put_item(Item=hotel)

    except Exception as e:
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": json.dumps({
                "Error": "Uploading the hotel photo failed"
            })
        }

    logger.debug('Info')

    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': headers,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello')
    }
```